# joining two tables based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

I have a list of clients that I'm trying to pull, but am not exactly sure if I'm doing it right. I have about 20 thounsand records to go through and just hope that I do it the right way. Basically I have 2 different client tables, that happen to belong to 2 different applications, but are stored in the same database.

A client, John Doe (ex) can be in both client tables with different client id's, however, have a uniqueID that is the same in both tables. So for example John Doe can have clientID = 7 in tbl1, and ClientID = 11 in tb2, but in both Client tables teh UniqueID is 129009.

Here's the basic structure. These are the first 2 tables.

```
tblClient1                             tblServiceClient1
ClientID        UniqueID               ClientID          ClientServiceType
17              12345                  17                8
15              34567                  15                8
```

Second set of tables is

```
tblClient2                             tblClientService2
ClientID        UniqueID               ClientID           ClientServiceType
58              12345                  58                 8
89              34567                  89                 7
```

What I'm hoping to get is a list of clients, from both sets of tables where:
-Client must exist in tblClient1 & tblClient2 
-Client must have ClientServiceType = 8 in tblClientServiceType1 & tblClientServiceType2

here's what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
ClientID1            ClientID2           UniqueID
17                   58                  12345
```

So I will need to join the tables where clients in both ClientID tables have the same UniqueID and both clients have ClientSErviceType = 8

I only see this one client, because the other client has ClientServiceType = 7

```
  Select tblClient1.ClientID, tblClient2.ClientID, tblClient1.UniqueID
       From tblClient1 
       inner join tblClientService1 on tblClient1.ClientID = tblClientService1.ClientID 
       inner join tblClient2 on tblClient1.UniqueID = tblClient2.UniqueID 
       inner join tblServiceClient2 on tblClient2.ClientID = tblServiceClient2.ClientID
  Group By tblClient1.ClientID, tblClient2.ClientID, tblClient1.UniqueID
  Having tblServiceClient1.ClientServiceType = 8 and tblServiceClient2.ClientServiceType=8
```

Comment: JOIN all 4 tables.

Comment: You would just use an AND predicate in your join.

Comment: I did it with Inner Join, but for ClientServiceType, should I do this like this: Having(tblClientServiceType2 = 8 and tblClientServiceType1 = 8) or Should I do this with the join? @SeanLange

Comment: `Having` is for filtering GROUP-ed queries on Aggregate functions.  You don't need it here.  Put all your conditions in your joins.

Comment: I'd do a GROUP BY because it pulls up duplicate records if they exists in both tables @TabAlleman

Comment: That is an indication that your join predicates are not correct. This happens when you need to have multiple predicates to join.

Comment: You might need to show us your entire query, current results and desired results in order to get a complete answer.   But you definitely don't need to use `HAVING` to test if a `ServiceType=8`.

Comment: @TabAlleman this is what I currently have, but I am worried that it might pull all records correctly

Comment: @SeanLange I have added the query.

Comment: Why are you worried?   Can't you run the query and see if it pulls the records correctly or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your query as an example (which seems like it would return the data you want) I simplified it a bit. I also used aliases, notice how it cut down the amount of text significantly which makes it a lot easier to read.

```
Select c1.ClientID
    , c2.ClientID
    , c1.UniqueID
From tblClient1 c1
inner join tblClientService1 cs1 on c1.ClientID = cs1.ClientID 
inner join tblClient2 c2 on c1.UniqueID = c2.UniqueID 
inner join tblServiceClient2 sc2 on c2.ClientID = sc2.ClientID
    AND cs1.ClientServiceType = sc2.ClientServiceType
where cs1.ClientServiceType = 8
```

Comment: Ok so I was on the right track. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You were definitely going the right direction. Think you got derailed a little when you started grouping. Glad I could help you to the finish line.